# Cannot associate VC variables to ones retrieved in a Method

Tags: ios, swift, variables, methods, viewdidload

In the ViewController I set two variables called `post` and `user` respectively of type **Post** and **aUser**, two types I created that contains all the information needed.

The ViewDidLoad Method of the VC looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateViewDetail()
    }
```

It calls updateViewDetail() method which retrieves the correct user and post object from a Firebase Realtime database:

```
func updateViewDetail(){
        Api.Post.observePost(with: postID) { (post) in
            let postretrieved = post
            print("post id inside \(postretrieved.caption)")
            guard let postUid = postretrieved.uid else{
                return
            }

            self.fetchUsers(uid: postUid) {
                self.post = post
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

            print("the post in the function : \(post.id)")
        }
    }

    func fetchUsers(uid: String, completed: @escaping ()-> Void){
        Api.theUser.observeUser(withID: uid) { (user) in
            self.user = user
            print("the user in the function is : \(user.id)")
            completed()
        }
    }
```

**The goal of the methods** is to equal the post and user retrieved from the database to the ones I declared in the ViewController such that I can display them on a TableView later.

The problem is that when I try to print the user or post inside the methods (as displayed in the code up) I see the correct output, the user is retrieved and printed correctly.
But when I try to print it in viewDidLoad Method it prints nil.

It seems like the `self.post = post` and `self.user = user` associations don't work properly and don't equal the VC variable to the one retrieved in the method. Do you know how can I solve this?

EDIT 1: the variable **user** and **post** set inside the ViewController are used for setting the values in a UITableView using a custom UITableViewCell. The code is down here:
1) firstly I set the tableViewDatasource equal to the ViewController.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateViewDetail(onUserRetrieved: { (user) in
            self.user = user
        }) { (post) in
            self.post = post
        }
       tableView.dataSource = self
    }
```

Then I let the VC conforms to the protocol setting the required methods:

```
extension DetailViewController : UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
        cell.post = self.post
        cell.user = self.user

       return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

}
```

When I run the application I get an **error** saying that the values inside post and user of HomeTableViewCell are nil, thus the app crashes.

Comment: This may be because the code is running asynchronously.

Comment: You are doing asynchronous calls so the print statements in `viewDidLoad` gets executed before the data is returned from Firebase. So your code works fine most likely. In `fetchUsers` ,try to print from the `completed` closure instead.

Comment: Here is an article about it, [What “asynchronous” means](http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/). To the community, this question shows up all the time, is there a suitable question to use as the go-to close as duplicate question for this?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the user and post retrieving is asynchronous, So you need to be triggered once the data is ready for use.

I have re-writen your code part as follows:

> ```
> override func viewDidLoad() {
>     super.viewDidLoad()
>     updateViewDetail(onUserRetrieved: { user in print(user)}, onPostRetrieved: { post in print(post)})
> }
>
> func updateViewDetail(onUserRetrieved: @escaping (User) -> Void, onPostRetrieved: @escaping (Post) -> Void ){
>     Api.Post.observePost(with: postID) { (post) in
>         let postretrieved = post
>         print("post id inside \(postretrieved.caption)")
>         guard let postUid = postretrieved.uid else{
>             return
>         }
>
>         onPostRetrieved(post)
>
>         self.fetchUsers(uid: postUid) { user in
>             self.post = post
>             onUserRetrieved(user)
>             self.tableView.reloadData()
>         }
>
>         print("the post in the function : \(post.id)")
>     }
> }
>
> func fetchUsers(uid: String, completed: @escaping (User)-> Void){
>     Api.theUser.observeUser(withID: uid) { (user) in
>         self.user = user
>         print("the user in the function is : \(user.id)")
>         completed(user)
>     }
> }
>
> func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
>     return self.post != nil && self.user != nil ? 1 : 0
> }
> ```

Comment: It works but when I try to charge the tableview with those datas(post and user) are still nil. I can't get why How can I upload data on tableview when the data has just been retrieved and not before.

Comment: Can you show the tableview data source functions to check with you ?

Comment: Check my edit in the Answer for handling number of rows delegate.

Comment: I tried it but the problem remains. I think that the issue is on why the post and user property of the VC when are passed to the tableViewDatasource are nil. I assume that tableviewDataSource charges data before user and post are set in the VC. so the variables when the tableview charges data are nil. thus the run of the app crashes. How can I load the tableView **AFTER** the data (post and user) are set?

Comment: This edit shall return 0 incase the data hasn’t been ready yet. So once you got the data and reload the tsble view, this function returns 1 to call the cellForRow function and draw the cell.         func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.post != nil && self.user != nil ? 1 : 0
        }